# Nginx multiple load balancers or single load blanacer

Tags: node.js, networking, nginx, docker, load-balancing

When deploying an application with multiple tiers is it preferable have individual Nginx load-balancers for API and Web servers? Or a single LB serving both the API and Web servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the simpler solution of a single load balancer until it's clear that they need be separate.

If Nginx is the load balancer, you can use different logging and configurations to customize differences between the "web" backend and the "api" backend.

Comment: Although, i hesitate for this solution as all load would be going through a single LB. A single point of failure, if the API goes down the web is still running off cache and serving

Comment: Docker makes this a breeze

Comment: Whether you have one conceptual load balancer for both backends or two, Having a high-availability solution for your load balancers is a good idea, in case one of the LBs dies. The Amazon Elastic Load Balancer takes care of that for you.  For a host-your-own solution, Heartbeat can be used to automatically failover to a twin LB.

Comment: yes i can see the point here, also with docker its not really possible to expose to containers on a single port anyway...

Answer (score 0):

So there is a lot to consider when node balancing, with node I personally use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) in cluster mode (for machine local clusters) and nigix as the overall load balancer (and static host).

Remember when load balancing, depending on the app, sessions and communication between the nodes requires infrastructure (redis, mongodb)

[pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) (locally) can deploy a node app to each cpu core and manage load balancing all in one command `pm2 start app.js -i 4` this can be spread across multiple nodes.

Comment: I just feel PM2 is another layer, each layer adds latency, complexity and maintenance. Also i ran across a number of PM2 bugs whilst using it. Plus...... Its node I have read not to use any form of node load balancing. stick to something that does it better HAProxy or nginx